# Passing props to a dynamically created component

Tags: reactjs, redux, components

I dynamically create a component and like to pass some props into it as the following

```
import ResouceUsageGadget from './ResouceUsage/ResouceUsageGadget'
  constructor() {
    ...
    this.gadgetStateMap = {
            "ResouceUsageGadget":{"name":"ResouceUsageGadget", "type":ResouceUsageGadget, "state":"normal"}
    }
  }
...
render(){
  let aa = this.gadgetStateMap["ResouceUsageGadget"].type
  return (
     <aa gadgets={this.props.gadgets}/>
  )
}

const DashboardContainer = connect(
          store => {
                return {
                    gadgets: store.DashboardReducer.gadgets
                };
              }
            )(_DashboardContainer);
export default DashboardContainer
```

I got a warning:

Warning: Unknown prop `gadgets` on  tag. Remove this prop from the element. 
    in aa (created by _DashboardContainer)
    in div (created by _DashboardContainer)
    in div (created by _DashboardContainer)
    in _DashboardContainer (created by Connect(_DashboardContainer))
    in Connect(_DashboardContainer) (created by _MainContainer)

And the component never shown up...

Anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Uhm, try doing this:

```
import ResouceUsageGadget from './ResouceUsage/ResouceUsageGadget'
  constructor() {
    ...
    this.gadgetStateMap = {
            "ResouceUsageGadget":{"name":"ResouceUsageGadget", "type":ResouceUsageGadget, "state":"normal"}
    }
  }
...
render(){
  let aa = React.createElement(this.gadgetStateMap["ResouceUsageGadget"].type, 
                               {'gadgets': this.props.gadgets})
  return (
     {aa}
  )
}

const DashboardContainer = connect(
          store => {
                return {
                    gadgets: store.DashboardReducer.gadgets
                };
              }
            )(_DashboardContainer);
export default DashboardContainer
```

the `<aa/>` component is actually an html tag just like `<input/>`, not the component you imported `ResouceUsageGadget`.

Answer (score 0):

From the [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html#rendering-a-component):

> #### Caveat:
>
> Always start component names with a capital letter.
> For example, `<div />` represents a DOM tag, but `<Welcome />` represents a component and requires `Welcome` to be in scope.

Try changing

```
render(){
  let aa = this.gadgetStateMap["ResouceUsageGadget"].type
  return (
     <aa gadgets={this.props.gadgets}/>
  )
}
```

to be

```
render(){
  let Aa = this.gadgetStateMap["ResouceUsageGadget"].type
  return (
     <Aa gadgets={this.props.gadgets}/>
  )
}
```

and see if that helps.